# Mongoose InsertMany - how to get count of inserted documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After InsertMany with Mongoose , how can we know how many documents have succeeded to get into the DB ?

```
  Employees.insertMany(employees)
        .then(function(docs) {
          // do something with docs
          console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + ... );
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          // error handling here
          console.log("Failed to insert Bulk..." + err.message);
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

When the insert finishes, it returns an array with all the documents so you can use the `length` property to find out how many there are:

```js
Employees.insertMany(employees)
  .then(function(docs) {
    console.log(docs.length);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```